# Reading Directory Listing of a Remote Server folder in Obj-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to list all the files contained in a folder at a remote server and save the URLs of the files in an array.

Any idea, how can I do that?

Comment: How do you connect to the remote server? ftp? http? ssh? Do you have access to the server so you can decide its implementation?

Comment: Yes Claus, I have access to the FTP Server. To retrieve directory Listing, I make use of [CFFTPStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFFTPStreamRef/Reference/reference.html) and after that it is job of NSURLConnection. You can also refer to the Apple's demo application [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html).