# How to determine the file extension of a file from a URL (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, download

I have a URL of type: http://example.com/files/
And I need to determine what file is there (extension and name of file). Depending on extensions, I'll do something. 
How can I determine it?

Comment: *Duplicate question*!
Did you try searching and reading similar questions and answers first?
Here are some of them:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921523/get-list-of-files-with-specific-extensions-at-a-specified-path-in-objective-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267517/copy-or-list-files-of-a-remote-folder-given-the-url-using-objective-c-is or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567711/get-all-folders-of-url or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094650/reading-directory-listing-of-a-remote-server-folder-in-obj-c

Comment: Sorry, I saw its, but this answers is not good for my situation.  My  URL is http://client.visionshop.me/Img/GetCertificateImage/2057.  Script from this URL generate downloading file. And I don't know, how I can find filename and extension for file from generated link.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
NSString *ext = [[url lastPathComponent] pathExtension];
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407801-pathextension

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code directly just passing your NSUrl and get File Extension in return.

```
- (NSString *)findExtensionOfFileInUrl:(NSURL *)url{

    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    NSArray *componentsArray = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *fileExtension = [componentsArray lastObject];
    return  fileExtension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
NSURL *urll = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/files/firstFile.com"];
    NSString *filenameWithExtension = [urll lastPathComponent];

    NSRange *range = [filenameWithExtension rangeOfString:@"."];
```

> USing the **substringWithRange**  just substring of those ....

```
 NSString *fileName = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
    NSString *extension = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(10, string.length - range.location-1)];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", fileName, extension);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't name of file "firstFile". Only domain and name of catalogue.  This catalogue have script, that start download something file. And i need find file for this URL and extensions for this files. My  URL is http://client.visionshop.me/Img/GetCertificateImage/2057